# How to search and launch an already installed ipad application from another ipad application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on a iPad application which need to identify its related application is already installed in the iphone/ ipad. If it already installed in the device, i had to launch it from my application.

Can we do search in client iPad as the requested app have installed or not?

How to launch another application from my application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot search for installed applications, but you *can* open another app via a custom URL scheme. There is no guarantee that there is not another app handling that particular scheme, though.

You might as well think about sharing data using the keychain.

Comment: You can ask the system if it can open a custom URL scheme, that way you can check if an app is installed.

Comment: @rckoenes Well, sort of. You can only get the information if *any* app will open that scheme.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly check for the presence of another app, and you cannot directly launch another app.

But if the other app supports an URL scheme you can use [-[UIApplication canOpenURL:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL%3a) to check whether that URL scheme is supported (and thus the app is installed, if the URL scheme is sufficiently unique). You can then launch the other app via [-[UIApplication openURL:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL%3a).

If you need to exchange data that's too big to be passed via an URL parameter, use a [UIPasteboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html) (if both apps are from you).